# ffmpeg does not recognise text='%{frame_num}'

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay the current frame number on a video, and i have this currently:

```
ffmpeg -i twopeople.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy twopeopleOUTPUT.mp4
```

The output has `x=(w-tw)` instead of the current frame. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Works here. Share full log.

Comment: After further investigation it seems to only happen when I run the command from a .bat file. If I run it straight in cmd it works. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Escape the % with another %

Answer (score 1):

In `.bat` escape the `%` with another `%`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='%%{frame_num}'" output.mp4
```